# Get first char from string - error with latin character

Tags: c++, tcp

I have a problem while sending latin character from TCP server to a client.

Short example:

```
string temp = "ąszcz";
SendToAll(temp); //clients reveices ąszcz

// get first char
char* chr = &temp.at(0);
chr[0+1] = NULL;
string firstChar(chr);

SendToAll(firstChar); //clients receives ?
```

This is how exactly it looks in terminal:

[image]

Can you tell me what is wrong there?

Comment: probably your terminal can not print the character correctly. What terminal do you use?

Comment: Crom only knows what `SendToAll` did. [mcve] please.

Comment: Also are you absolutely certain about the encoding of 'ą'? You could have trashed the later part of a multi-byte character.

Comment: @FrankS101 as you can see on the picture, terminal is printing `ą` correctly. But only if it is sent as a string.

Comment: They are both strings, but one string has exactly one character. My suspicion is 'ą' is larger than one character and you've pasted a zero in on top of part of it. Example: https://ideone.com/bPPAfx should output 2 unless a multibyte character came into play

Comment: Doest `SendToAll` support `wstring` as well? If so, you can use `wstring` together with `wchar_t*` pointer because this character is two bytes (0x0105) character.